# Changing url for sub-site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm planning to change URL of sub site. But I would like to understand  will it be cause to the problems for end users?How can I avoid to causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is easy to change the URL of subsite , but it will cause havoc if your users aren't expecting it .

You can using explorer view and SharePoint designer to modify your subsite URL .

Then You can manually send an email notification end user .

Or using event receiver : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5c546dbc-594f-40e0-a29b-8a25ac11100e/change-subsite-url-and-title-using-workflow-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointgeneral .